# Jquery get Checkbox in span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have some jquery code where I am trying to select a checkbox when the user clicks on a div. My fiddle is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/5PpsJ/

What i have come up with is this, but it is not selecting the checkbox inside of the span:

```
$('span[name="' + current + '"]').closest('input:checkbox[id="CB_Selected"]').prop('checked', true);
```

The full code is in the link

My question is how can i get the select box inside of the span based on its unique name and select it?

n.b I have commented out the hide functio0n in jquery to visually see whether the checkbox is selected or not

**EDIT**
My ID's are the same because I am working inside of ASP.NET and using a repeater to create the HTML shown in the fiddle. Inside of Repeaters I can not set the ID of item as the Repeater control does not allow me to set the ID with `Eval(datasource)`

Comment: Your fiddle markup is invalid. An ID should be unique to ***one*** and ***only one*** element on the page at any given time.

Comment: You are working with ASP.NET then why did you not tagged it properly. Also add your repeater markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are unique. All you need is this:

```
$("#CB_Selected").prop('checked', true);
```

Actually, you don't even need jQuery:

```
document.getElementByID('CB_Selected').checked = true;
```

---

As others have pointed out, it would be preferred to use a class rather than an ID if there are multiple checkboxes. In addition, an `input` cannot have children, so the `closest` function won't work; did you mean `find` (for children) or `siblings`?

Comment: +1 Note that while this is correct, due to the OP's invalid markup (using the same ID on multiple checkboxes) this would not work.

Comment: I dont think i can do this. I am working inside of ASP.net and using a repeater to create the Checkboxes dynamically, and thus cant set the ID of the checkbox because Repeater item ID's cannot be set inside of a repeater

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving several checkboxes the same ID -- which invalidates your html -- use a class on the checkboxes. Change:

```
<input id="CB_Selected" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper$ctl01$Repeater_Selected$ctl00$CB_Selected" />
```

To:

```
<input class="CB_Selected" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder_Content_Wraper$ctl01$Repeater_Selected$ctl00$CB_Selected" />
```

Then you can use the code:

```
$('#s_' + this.id).find(':checkbox.CB_Selected').prop('checked', true);
```